# Oracle SQL - Distinct Continuous Range of Dates

Tags: sql, oracle

Given a table with columns representing a start and end:

```
Start        End
01/01/2016   03/01/2016
01/01/2016   06/01/2016
```

I'm trying to build a query that can recognize that the distinct set of ranges is the following:

```
[01/01/2016, 03/01/2016)
[03/01/2016, 06/01/2016)
```

What is this concept called and how can I achieve it with SQL ?

Comment: Well, how **exactly** would you define the set of ranges? If you try to answer this question you might find yourself very close to the answer...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can bring all the dates together and use `lead()`:

```
with d as (
      select start as dte
      from t
      union  -- on purpose to remove duplicates
      select end as dte
      from t
     )
select dte as start, lead(dte) over (order by dte) as end
from d;
```

If you want to prevent the final `NULL` value . . .

```
select d.*
from (select dte as start, lead(dte) over (order by dte) as end
      from d
     ) d
where end is not null;
```

Answer (score 0):

select lag(end_date,1,start_date) over(order by end_date) start_date,end_date from jtest14;